# How to assign values to a type with optional properties?

Tags: typescript

Here is my type:

```
export type Supply = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    manufacturer?: string;
    model?: string;
}
```

Here is how I try to assign to an object with that type:

```
return response['data']['supplies'].map((supply: ServerResponse.Supply) => {
    let s = {
        id: supply['supply_id'],
        name: supply['name'],
    }

    if ('manufacturer' in supply) {
        s.manufacturer = supply['manufacturer']
    }

    if ('model' in supply) {
        s.model = supply['model']
    }

    return s;
});
```

I get the TypeScript warnings:

> [ts] Property 'manufacturer' does not exist on type '{ id: number;
> name: string; }'.
>
> [ts] Property 'model' does not exist on type '{ id:
> number; name: string; }'

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the type info :

```
let s: Supply = {
        id: supply['supply_id'],
        name: supply['name'],
}
```

else TS will assume that your variable `s` has its own type `{id: number, name: string}` based on the initial declaration